# Schedule Windows Service to run once daily

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have a stored procedure written in SQL Server 2008 R2 that needs to run daily. The stored procedure accepts as parameters two dates `start date` & `end date` and based on these dates it fetches data from `table A` and writes it to `table B`.

In order to automate the task of running the stored procedure daily, I have written a Windows service. I have scheduled my task in `Service1.cs` as follows:

```
System.Timers.Timer oTimer = null;

public ServiceExample()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
   SetTimer();
}

private void SetTimer()
{
   DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
   int intervalToElapse = 0;
   DateTime scheduleTime = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, 8, 0, 0); //run at 8 am every morning

   if (currentTime <= scheduleTime)
      intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;
   else
      intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.AddDays(1).Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;

   oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(intervalToElapse);
   oTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(oTimer_Elapsed);

   oTimer.Start();
}

void oTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   //make connection to SQL and call the SP
   DBLibrary oDBLibrary = new DBLibrary();
   DataSet dsCustomer = oDBLibrary.getCustomerDetails();
   oTimer.Interval = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   SetTimer();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
   oTimer.Stop();
}
```

The call to the stored procedure is as follows:

```
public DataSet getCustomerDetails()
{
    DateTime First_Date = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime dateOnly = First_Date.Date;
    DateTime First_Date1 = dateOnly.AddDays(-1); // assign back to see the new instance
    DateTime End_Date = DateTime.Now;

    SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    oSqlConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand oSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
    oSqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
    oSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oSqlCommand.CommandText = "Daily_Airtime_Summary";

    oSqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = First_Date1;
    oSqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = End_Date;
    oSqlCommand.Connection = oSqlConnection;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter oSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oSqlCommand);
    oSqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

    oSqlConnection.Close();
    return ds;
 }
```

The issues I am facing:

1. Even though the scheduled time is 8 am and I debug my service at around 10 am, it starts to run (execute stored procedure) immediately.
2. The idea is to call/run the stored procedure `once`. However, when I check `table B`, I see the same data being populated almost 17 times.
3. The dates passed in the parameters is `start date = yesterday's date` and `end date = today's date`. However, I see the procedure running continuously taking `start date = today's date` once the date with `start date = yesterday's date` and `end date = today's date` has been fetched (multiple times).

Can anyone guide here please?

Comment: Your parameters don't depend on data from your service, so you can just create a job on SQL Server.

Comment: Where do you keep track whether the call has been made for a given day, or not? You need to somehow store that information somewhere and check for it... also: if you run this only once a day, I wouldn't go through the trouble of creating a service - just create a **console application** that you can schedule using Windows Scheduled Tasks to run once a day.... much simpler...

Comment: @marc_s I will look into **console application** but at the moment I want to get this to work first. My question is why is the stored procedure being called multiple times at the same instance instead of the service going to `sleep` once the stored procedure has been executed?

Comment: What about just using Task Scheduler or SQL Server Agent? Windows Services are complicated.

Comment: Any pointers in using that @usr ? No luck getting the `Windows Service` issue resolved...

Comment: @Sarah can only point you to Google to find out what these things are. Ask something specific if you hit a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic for time to run the proc. That may not be initialized properly causing the proc torrun on initial start.

Also,  to debug this you need to install as a service using the. Net  utility that points the service executable at the debug version in your project. Complie in debug mode,  start the service with the windows service utility in control panel, then in Visual Studio attach to that process.